# How to Pass the data from one component to another angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have a navigation bar in which i have cart , and i have a view product component in which i can show the list of the product and add the product into the main cart .
How can i pass the value to the main component from the product component.So, that i can be reflected in the cart of main component.

I have tried:
Product Component:

```
    @Component({
      selector:'product',
      template:'Poduct List is getting rendered here and here is a 
      button by clicking the button onClick() method will be called
      and item added into service .This whole template is running in for loop'
    })

    @Input itemAdded:number;

    onClick()
    {
     itemAdded++;
     service.setCartItem(itemAdded);
    }
```

Sorry i could not able to paste the code as its too big.

Main Component:

```
<div class="cart"><product [itemAdded]="valueCommingfromService"></div>
```

The problem is along with the cart value all other html element that is a part of `product` selector is getting rendered in the main component i.e: the product list also.

Please suggest me how i can achive this.

Comment: I just don't get the question, but you didn't close  the "product" tag.

Comment: There are plenty of questions about passing data between components in Angular2. Just look for them.

Comment: sorry product is a typo in actual its closed properly

Comment: modified my quetion i hope it will be little more clear what i am trying to do.

Comment: use two way binding with the ngModule

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [official document from Angular2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-local-var) Below is the code sample -

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'hero-child',
  template: `
   <h3>{{hero.name}} says:</h3>
   <p>I, {{hero.name}}, am at your service, {{masterName}}.</p>`
})
export class HeroChildComponent {
  @Input() hero: Hero;
  @Input('master') masterName: string;
}
```

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/angular-2-two-ways-to-pass-data) is one more link which I recommend for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Main compoent :

```
<div class="cart"><product [itemAdded] ="passthevaluehere" /></div>
```

In the component to which you need to get the passed value

```
@Component({
  inputs:["itemAdded"]
})

export class Conponent{
  private itemAdded={}
}
```

I hope this one solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have suggested, the question is very unclear but appears to be a duplicate of a frequently asked question.  To your specific question regarding html being displayed in your main component - this is because you didn't close your product tag:

```
<div class="cart"><product [itemAdded]="valueCommingfromService"></product></div>
```

Another thing - you aren't using your onClick method at all in your template.  You should rename it and bind the renamed method to the click directive:

```
<div class="cart"><product [itemAdded]="valueCommingfromService" (click)="myMethod()"></product></div>
```

Comment: Yes i am sorry for that i could not able to present all the code here. But,again for your understanding i am closing the product tag properly. But, inspite of this also all other thing in the product selector are getting displayed.Also, i don't required the (click) in this div i just want to show value inside it . onClick is used in the product page where each product is inside one dive and having button to add into card. Just like you see on amazon,or flipkart